# What is the name/type of this soldering iron tip?

Tags: soldering, tools, soldering-iron-station

I have a soldering iron station called [Dibotech soldering station 60W](https://www.kjell.com/se/produkter/el-verktyg/verktyg/lodning/lodverktyg/dibotech-lodstation-pro-60-w-p40570) which is a temperature controlled soldering station. You can set the temperature of the tip between 50-480 degrees Celsius.

The problem is I can not find the name of the tip to the pen. I contacted the sellers but they had no name for it.

I found [800L-T-B](https://www.hakko.com/english/tip_selection/series_900l.html) which looks similar but which I can't find the inside and outside measurements of it. Is these standard measurements?

Can I buy a new soldering pen with all the same functionalities and assume it will work? Or are not every soldering station compatible even if the contact is?

Here is image of the tip and it's measurements
[image: soldering iron tip measurements]

Comment: That looks nonstandard. There may be no reliable name. Could it be a conical tip that has been damaged? IMO conical tips suck anyways.

Comment: I do think the tip is somewhat damaged, it is supposed to be 0.5mm but what I can measure it is at minimum ~1mm

Comment: Looks like a fake Hakko see if it matches official dimensions or if it's just visually similar but a different size

Comment: I'm not sure about dimensions, but it looks from the image pretty much like the ones that go in one of Hakko's budget irons (like the one that comes with the FX-888D). Maybe it's compatible?

Comment: Generally, solder stations cannot be assumed to be compatible. You'll want some manner of statement that the tip is suitable for solder station "x".

Comment: From measuring one, the depth of the hole in a Hakko T18-BR02 tip is 23 mm, but the diameter of the hole is only about 3.95 mm and the outside diameter is 6.80 mm. Also, the Hakko tip has a different shoulder shape. So it looks like tips for the FX-888D will *not* fit your soldering iron.

Comment: Is [Dibotech Extra lödspetsar](https://www.kjell.com/se/produkter/el-verktyg/verktyg/lodning/lodverktyg/dibotech-extra-lodspetsar-till-40407-4-pack-p40408) what you need?